# Foreach with recursion

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, recursion, foreach

I created a function which calculating all UNIQUE posts in categories and their subcategories (UNIQUE because some posts can be in few different categories).

But I know that it is inaccurate code.
Please help me to construct it on right way. So it will accept the unlimited level of subcategories.

Thank you so much in advance.

This is my code:

```
public function countAllCatPosts($category, $postIds = array()){
        
        $catPosts = $category->posts->pluck('id')->toArray();
        $postIds = array_merge($postIds, $catPosts);
        
        foreach($category->categories as $childCategory){
            
            $catPosts = $childCategory->posts->pluck('id')->toArray();
            $postIds = array_merge($postIds, $catPosts);                        
                                
            foreach($childCategory->categories as $childCategory1){
                
                $catPosts = $childCategory1->posts->pluck('id')->toArray();
                $postIds = array_merge($postIds, $catPosts);    
                
                foreach($childCategory1->categories as $childCategory2){
                    
                    $catPosts = $childCategory2->posts->pluck('id')->toArray();
                    $postIds = array_merge($postIds, $catPosts);
                    
                    foreach($childCategory2->categories as $childCategory3){
                        
                        $catPosts = $childCategory3->posts->pluck('id')->toArray();
                        $postIds = array_merge($postIds, $catPosts);
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
                                                            
        }
                    
        $total = count(array_unique($postIds));
        
        return $total;    
        
    }
```

Comment: is  `$category` is a laravel model instance?  if it is a model , is it have relationship to same model like `parent_id`?

Comment: Yes it's laravel model instance. But how it helped I need to count all unique posts in every child category. And return total to the very top-level category. The answer from John Tyner works. Or maybe you have another better option without foreach loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're after

```
public function countAllCatPosts($category, $postIds = array()){        
        $postIds = $this->getChildren($category, $postIds);
        $total = count(array_unique($postIds));
        return $total; 
}

public function getChildren($children, $postIds) {
        $catPosts = $children->posts->pluck('id')->toArray();
        $postIds = array_merge($postIds, $catPosts);
        foreach($children->categories as $childCategory){
             $postIds = $this->getChildren($childCategory, $postIds);
        }
        return $postIds;
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. It helped. Working like a charm! You did a small mistake but I have fixed it. Instead of foreach($catPosts as $childCategory) in the getChildren() function should be  foreach($children->categories as $childCategory).

Thank you again! You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: will you be able to look at another issue with similar conditions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452861/how-to-get-total-items-in-collection-relationship Will be very glad if you can help. Thank you.