# How to get total items in collection relationship

Tags: laravel, recursion, collections, laravel-collection

I have a function that generates the tree of categories:
I want to count how many posts exist in the parent category including all levels of subcategories. I have created a code that counts only two levels. But I want it to support unlimited levels.

```
private function buildMenu(): void
    {
        $this->menu = new Collection();
        $this->postCategories = PostCategory::with('posts')->orderBy('order')->get();


        foreach ($this->postCategories as $postCategory) {
            if ($postCategory->isTopLevelParent()) {

                $subChildren = $this->getChildren($postCategory, 1);
                $this->menu->push(new MenuItem([
                    'count'     => $this->countPosts($postCategory, $subChildren),
                    'children'  => $subChildren,
                    'offset'    => 0,
                    'category'  => null,
                ]));
            }
        }


        $this->menu->prepend(new MenuItem([
            'count'     => $this->getAllPostCount(),
            'children'  => collect([]),
            'offset'    => 0,
            'category'  => null,
        ]));

    }

private function getChildren(PostCategory $parentCategory, int $offset): Collection
{
    $children = collect([]);
    foreach ($this->postCategories as $postCategory) {
        if ($postCategory->parent_id === $parentCategory->id) {

            $subChildren = $this->getChildren($postCategory, $offset + 1);

            $children->push(new MenuItem([
                'count'     => $this->countPosts($postCategory, $subChildren),
                'children'  => $subChildren,
                'offset'    => $offset,
                'category'  => $postCategory,
            ]));
        }
    }

    return $children;

}


private function countPosts(PostCategory $postCategory, Collection $children): int
{

    $postIds = $postCategory->posts->pluck('id')->toArray();

    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $postIds = array_merge($postIds, $child->category->posts->pluck('id')->toArray());
        $child->category = null;
    }
    return count(array_unique($postIds));
}
```

I have post_categories table where I have ID and PARENT ID.

Then I have table called post_category where I have post_id and category_id

And in the end I have POSTS table WHERE POSTS.ID have relationship with POST_ID from POST_CATEGORY table.

PostCategory MODEL. I have deleted unused functions from the model otherwise I was not able to edit the question

```
class PostCategory extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_category', 'category_id', 'post_id');
    }

    public function featuredPosts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_category_featured', 'category_id', 'post_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PostCategory::class, 'parent_id')->orderBy('name');
    }

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PostCategory::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function isTopLevelParent(): bool
    {
        return $this->parent_id === null;
    }


    public static function withChildren(): Builder
    {
        return self::with('children.children.children.children.children.children.children');
    }

}
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I think it will be better if you share your models and their relationships along with the data structure. What is the entry point here? Is it a post or subcategory? I mean parent of what?

Comment: I'm not sure that it is necessary. You can see the getChildren function which is recursion. This function builds a multilevel tree for the menu. And for every menu item it's trying to count all posts in the category by countPosts function: 
'count' => $this->countPosts($postCategory, $subChildren). I guess I need to add something in countPosts function to get the total number of every child of category.

Comment: A category can have posts as well as a subcategory. And subcategories can have another subcategory with posts. So every top category level should count total of all subcategories posts.

Comment: You need to share the relations between the models, as your code is not optimal in any way, you are doing a lot of queries that you should avoid. Please share what @BülentAkgül is asking for so we can help you.

Comment: I added some additional code to the post. Please look. BTW, it's not my code. I just trying to improve it. As for me here there are too many dependencies.